# How do I center this image using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html

I have a parent div which contains a child div which contains an image I want to align that image horizontally in center but the code doesn't work.

I tried this but it didn't work

```css
#apnalogo {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
  <div class=";"><img src="/Users/Vinod-DT/Desktop/apnalogo1.png" id="apnalogo" height="80px" width="140px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `;` is not a valid class name. In any case, `text-align` works on the container, not the item being aligned.

Comment: Put your `text-align: center` on `#head`, not on the image